# How to add content page or view before tabbed page

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, tabbedpage

I want to add Page/View before `TabbedPage`, how can I do that?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"  
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
     xmlns:views="clr-namespace:TestProject.TabbedPages"  
     x:Class="TestProject.ItemPage"
     Title = "Home Page">
    <TabbedPage.Children>
    <views:AprovedLeaves Title="Approved leaves"/>
    <views:PendingLeaves Title="Pending leaves"/>
    <views:DeniedLeaves Title="Denied leaves"/>
    </TabbedPage.Children>
</TabbedPage>
```

Above code showing output like this

[image]

But I need some space before tabs. Like this

[image]

Comment: What i do not understand here is what do you mean, when you say you want to add a page/view in front of a TabbedPage!

Comment: I need some controls to show before tabs, after that I need tab pages. But as of now my tabs are showing on top itself. I want them down.

Comment: any XF "Page" type is intended to fill the entire screen.  You can achieve something close to what you want by using a segmented control instead of tabs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you use the Segmented Control Plugin for this look for `Plugin.Segmented`on Nuget and install Plugin.SegmentedControl.NetStandard

Initialize it on iOS something like this:

```
 SegementedControlRenderer.Initialize();
```

Then use it in XAML like this

```
  <control:SegmentedControl x:Name="SegmentedControl" SelectedSegment="{Binding SegmentSelection}" TintColor="White" SelectedTextColor="BlueViolet" DisabledColor="Gray" Margin="8,8,8,8">  
        <control:SegmentedControl.Children>  
            <control:SegmentedControlOption Text="Item 1" />  
            <control:SegmentedControlOption Text="Item 2" />  
            <control:SegmentedControlOption Text="Item 3" />  
            <control:SegmentedControlOption Text="Item 4" />  
        </control:SegmentedControl.Children>  
    </control:SegmentedControl>
```

A step by step guide is available on this [C# corner blog](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/segment-control-in-xamarin-forms/)

Feel free to revert in case of queries